# How to make a mysql query on mouse over and show it in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

I'm new here, but in my last searches, I found everything that I needed here, except this question.

I want create a dynamic tooltip with jquery or something else, but my question is, if I can do a mysql query when the user pass the mose over the text than I want, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="COL[1]" value="pmelendez" id="pmelendez" onmouseover="javascript:function_to_make_query(this.id);"/>pmelendez
```

And, in the function I need something like this:

```
<script>
 function_to_make_query(idreq){
  var result=<?php
  $q="SELECT complete_name from mydatabase where uname=" + idreq;
  $result=mysql_query($q,$my_conection);
  ?>
 }

</script>
```

But I need show the result on a tooltip or something like that.

For your help, thank you so much.

Comment: `$q="SELECT complete_name from mydatabase where uname=" + idreq;` -- this would NEVER work. That's not how you pass a JavaScript variable to PHP. See this question: [Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Comment: You would need to use AJAX, but every mouseover would hit your server with traffic.  Better to use a clicking mechanism.

Comment: It's an example my friend, for give an idea.

Comment: Why did you include the angularjs tag to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `mix` **javascript** and **php**. You have to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) like,

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="COL[1]" value="pmelendez" id="pmelendez"/>pmelendez
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#pmelendez').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:'tooltip.php',
       data:{id:this.id},
       success:function(response)
       {
          // use response for tooltip
       }
    });
});
```

**PHP- tooltip.php**

```
<?php
    $q="SELECT complete_name from mydatabase where uname=" + $_REQUEST['id'];
    $result=mysql_query($q,$my_conection);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array();
    echo $row['complete_name'];
?>
```

**Mysql** is `deprecated` so use **Mysqli**